# Magnetometers : on motor controler PCB or near motors?

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, magnetometer

For the cave robot I'm working on, it would be nice to have a magnetometer to get a (rough) orientation of the robot. By rough, I mean that 10° is more than enough, and even a +-45° error is still better than nothing.

The problem, is that there are a total of 16 motors on the robot (drawing usually a few hundreds milliamps, about 1A peak), which will generate some magnetic field.

So the question is whether a magnetometer will still give me a reasonable heading if I place it :

- directly on the main PCB, which is easiest, but which is also the one with the motor controllers on it, so probably "quite" bad from an magnetic point of view. The distance to the nearest motor would be about 4cm, and the distance to the nearest cable going to a motor about 2cm
- placing it as far as possible from the motors : less practical (requires separate PCB and wiring). About 12cm to the nearest motor and 3cm to the main PCB, and 5cm to motor wires.

What do you think, is it worse trying to put a magnetometer on the main PCB? (if it doesn't works, I can still add one farther away afterward).
Or is it even useless to plan one at all on my robot? (in which I will just place the IMU on the main PCB)

EDIT : the motors are small brushed DC gear-motors

Comment: Stop the robot whenever you take a heading reading.

Comment: Good idea, not sure how well it will work in practice : the robot has 8 "arms" with wheels at the end, and uses the arm motors to push the wheels against 2 opposit walls in order to avaoid slipping down.
So stopping the wheel's motors is no problem, but if I stop the arm motors, the robot will slip/fall down. But I might still cut them for a very short period of time, but I'm unsure if I can stop stem long enough for the current to become 0 in the motors.

So I will try it to improve accuracy, but I think it's best to design it in such way that I don't have to stop the motors

Comment: No clutches or worm gears anywhere?

Comment: No clutches nor worm gears, those are just small DC motors with ordinary gear reductor

Comment: maybe the trick is to generate an opposing field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lay the PCB out for both magnetometer and connector. (Use links or "do not fit" 0 ohm resistors where necessary to select either)

On board one will pick up HF switching from the motor controllers, but that's nothing compared to rotating fields from the motors themselves.

Magnetometer near a motor may even work *better* when the motor is running (if you filter out all the hash thoroughly enough) because when you stop a BLDC motor you can't be sure which pole of the rotor is closest : that adds an unknown stationary permanent magnet field to your readings. Maybe less of a problem with brushed PM motors (unless they are mounted on movable arms) but any remanent magnetism in an unpowered rotor will still add unknown terms.

You didn't say what type of motor, but I don't think it matters, there are so many unknowns here that I believe you'll have to answer your questions by experiment. To simplify which, allow alternative magnetometer mounting.

Comment: Thanks. Mounting a magnetometer on the PCB but still have an I2C connector to put it elsewhere was what I planned if I get no "clear" answere that the magnetometer will never work in one of the positions.
Basically :
- if someone is sure the magnetometer will not work on the PCB, then no point to put one there (maybe a simple IMU)
- if someone says it will work in neither place, then I place a simple IMU on the PCB
- in all other cases, I do as you suggest, and plan both locations.

PS : the motors are brushed DC motors

Comment: On-PCB is the best answer if it works. (I hope you have an IMU as well)

Comment: yes, I was hopping to use a "9 axis IMU" with accelerometer, magnetometer and gyro all in one.
I might have to move from that integrated solution anyway, as I just realised that JLCPCB hasn't any 9 axis IMU in stock right now, and excepted if I find one with MOQ of  1 or 2, I won't buy 10 or 100 to use just one. In that case, it will be IMU on the PCB and the magnetometer to be decided